# metacharacters in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, text

all

If I wanted to read a character from a .txt file and set the search boundaries (for just one char. space) to read "a digit 2 through 9 OR a lower-case character besides e", would one of the following two regexes be the correct way?

```
I. "[/w[2-9][a-z&&[^e]]]"
```

versus

```
II. "[[2-9][a-z&&[^e]]]"
```

I'm leaning towards the second one but I couldn't find anything in the java.util.regex.Pattern description that showed how to search for both a digit and a character simultaneously for the same position. Any help would be great. Thank you! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second regex is correct, but you don't need all those brackets.  This will do:

```
"[2-9a-z&&[^e]]"
```

This will be much more efficient than @ruakh's suggestion, `(?!e)[2-9a-z]`, which has to perform two tests at each position.  That's exactly the problem the Java devs were trying to solve with the intersection operator `&&`.  The Unicode Consortium has since endorsed the idea, along with other [set operations](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Subtraction_and_Intersection).

I don't know what you were trying for with that first regex, but the `/` and `w` will both be treated as literal characters, making it equivalent to `[2-9a-df-z/]`, which doesn't sound like what you want.

---

**EDIT:** Don't get me wrong though, efficiency is not the only reason to prefer this approach. It's not even the most important one. [Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) is as evil in regexes as it is anywhere else.  Concentrate on keeping your regexes as simple and clear as you can, and you shouldn't have to worry about performance.  My regex is both simpler (in that it only performs one *kind* of operation) and clearer (more readable) than the lookahead version (but not by much; that `&&` syntax still looks hideous to me).

Comment: great, thank you for the tip! I didn't even consider efficiency until you mentioned it...cheers! ^^

Comment: nice point, and thanks for the link; informative and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You would write:

```
[2-9a-df-z]
```

If you really want to write `a-z` with an explicit "not `e`", you could write:

```
(?!e)[2-9a-z]
```

but I think that's overkill for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[2-9a-df-z]`. This will match a digit from `2` to `9`, and all lower case characters except `e`, that is, from `a` to `d`, and from `f` to `z`.